# gtsam prints pointers instead of values

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm trying to run some of the gtsam library examples in one of my nodes. When one of the print function is called (i.e. `result.print("Final Result:\n");`) instead of printing values as shown in the [tutorial](https://gtsam.org/tutorials/intro.html), it prints pointers.

```
Final Result:

Values with 5 values:
Value 1: (gtsam::Pose2)
0x558a39e0fef0

Value 2: (gtsam::Pose2)
0x558a39e0ff50

Value 3: (gtsam::Pose2)
0x558a39e0cf10

Value 4: (gtsam::Pose2)
0x558a39e0cf70

Value 5: (gtsam::Pose2)
0x558a39e0cfd0
```

What can be the problem here? I installed the library with the procedure described [here](https://gtsam.org/get_started/). Is it useful to uninstall and reinstall the library? and if it is, how can I do it without messing up with my nodes that already use gtsam?

Any kind of feedback is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I use Ubuntu 18, ROS melodic and I have C++ nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372754/gtsam-prints-pointers-instead-of-values/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-25**:
I'm sorry to have to do this for something so seemingly unimportant, but please don't post screenshots of terminal text in question on ROS Answers. It's all text, so there is no need. Just copy-paste the text from the terminal into your question text. Do make sure to format it properly by selecting the text and pressing `ctrl+k` (or clicking the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it)).

You don't need to post a new question, just edit your curent one. You can use the `edit` button/link for this.

After you replace the screenshot with the error message itself, we can re-open your question.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-02-25**:
@gvdhoorn it requires more than 200 points to reopen a question

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-25**:
that's why I wrote:

> we can re-open your question.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2021-02-25**:
Sorry, i didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know what was causing the problem, but I managed to solve it like this:

- I uninstalled gtsam by executing `xargs rm -rf < install_manifest.txt` from the `build` directory of the gtsam package, as described [here](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam/issues/562).
- I deleted the whole gtsam package directory with `sudo rm -r gtsam/`
- I downloaded again the gtsam package by cloning the repository from [here](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam): `git clone https://github.com/borglab/gtsam.git`
- I reinstalled the package from source, as described [here](https://gtsam.org/get_started/).
  Note: I changed the `make check` and `make install` commands to `sudo make check` and `sudo make install` respectively.

Now the values are displayed as expected:

```
Final Result:

Values with 5 values:
Value 1: (gtsam::Pose2)
(-3.62586e-13, -1.35991e-12, -5.28358e-13)

Value 2: (gtsam::Pose2)
(2, -3.02085e-12, -7.54546e-13)

Value 3: (gtsam::Pose2)
(4, -3.9288e-11, 1.5708)

Value 4: (gtsam::Pose2)
(4, 2, 3.14159)

Value 5: (gtsam::Pose2)
(2, 2, -1.5708)
```

---

Originally posted by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) with karma: 51 on 2021-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hunterlineage1](https://answers.ros.org/users/110678/hunterlineage1/) on 2023-07-21**:
Is there a way to send gtsam::Values object, in your case the variable **result**, as a ROS message between nodes? I looked at creating custom ROS messages but I am confused on how to do this with gtsam::Values object and gtsam::NonlinearFactorGraph objects.